# Excel shortcut ctrl + . date formatting

Tags: excel

I was searching for simple solution to change date format for that shortcut

It gives me only DD.MM.YYYY. I need to use DD.MMM.YYYY.

I need to use it with text, so simple ctrl + 1 to change it to desired date doesn't work.

I changed it already in windows to DD.MMM.YYYY format.

Is there any solution to make that shortcut standard to DD.MMM.YYYY?

Comment: What shortcut? I don't understand. I don't have a `Ctrl + .` shortcut. Why not change the cell's formatting to show the date the way you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make your own shortcut.  Enter this sub into a standard module:

```
Sub DateAsText()
    With ActiveCell
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Format(Date, "DD.MMM.YYYY")
    End With
End Sub
```

Then assign a shortcut key-combo to the sub like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

When you touch the shortcut key-combo, the current date will be entered into the active cell as `Text` with the proper formatting:

[image]